# Tabulator table/grid dirty flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

Is there's a way to check if the **table** is **dirty** for the editor fields?

Seems like I can't see it on the documentation about the dirty table. If there's no implementation yet, then I would like to suggest a feature about it and that would be really nice to have.

All I know is you can get the initialValue and value of the cell then compare it.

E.g.(Table.isDirty(); will return true if fields are modified)

Something like Ext JS grid. The grid can check if inputs are dirty in one call only.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `isDirty` function as such, but there are events that are called when the table data is edited which will allow you to keep track of this.

When you have instantiated your table you should register the `cellEdited` event using the `on` function. When the table is edited by a user this function will be called, passing in the [Cell Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/components#component-cell) for the edited cell

```js
table.on("cellEdited", function(cell){
        //cell - cell component
});
```

For full details, checkout the [Cell Events Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/events#cell)